# jQuery self invoking function no access to variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript file that self invokes and I am trying to get the moduleID in my onClick event.

What am I doing wrong here? Another thing to note is that I have several of these files being included as "Widgets" all with their own moduleID. I am afraid that if I were to move this variable declaration above, making it a global, if its going to interfere with the other widgets that are also declaring a moduleID variable?

```
$(function() {

    // Define our vars
    var moduleID = 4,
        output = '';

... Some more stuff ...

});

//Listen for button click
$('[name=adminSearchGo]').click(function() {
    alert(moduleID); // No Access
});
```

Comment: Function at Question is call to `.ready()`, not IIFE. `moduleID` would be available within `.ready()` handler

Comment: Simply you can't access, because of different scopes. But, if you can keep the `moduleID` with the element itself (as `data-module-id="4"`) , then you can access as `$(this).data('module-id')` or `$(this).attr('data-module-id')`.

Comment: Or bind the click event ( `$('[name=adminSearchGo]').click` )  inside your previous function, where your `moduleID` is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything defined inside a function cannot be accessed outside the function.

What you can do is put your binding inside the `$(function(){...})` so that it can see the variables..

```
$(function() {

    // Define our vars
    var moduleID = 4,
        output = '';

  //Listen for button click
  $('[name=adminSearchGo]').click(function() {
    alert(moduleID); // No Access
  });

});
```

Also, depending on where this script runs, putting your `.click` binding outside `$(function(){...})` will potentially not work as the element might not exist yet. The entire purpose of `$(function(){...})` is to call the function when the DOM is ready.

Comment: I am a little confused by this line "What you can do is put your handler inside the $() callback so that it will be in the same scope."

Answer (score 0):

It's not about jQuery, it is about the javascript variable scope.
You can refer to this:
[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

As for the solution, you say that these files are included as widgets, so it's better to put all the behaviors of one module together inside this module. Like this:

```
$(function() {

    // Define our vars
    var moduleID = 4,
        output = '';

    ... Some more stuff ...


    //Listen for button click
    $('[name=adminSearchGo]').click(function() {
        alert(moduleID);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Function at Question is call to `.ready()`, not IIFE. `moduleID` would be available within `.ready()` handler, though you can also utilize `.data()` to attach an `moduleID`s, `output`'s to `document` as arrays within `document` `.data()` object; use separate `.ready()`: `$(function(){})` handlers to set `.data()`. Note, presently `this` is `document` within `.ready()` handler : `$(function(){})`

```js
$(function() {

  // Define our vars
  var moduleID = 4,
    output = '';
  $(this).data({
      "moduleID": [moduleID],
      output: [output]
    })
    // ... Some more stuff ...

});

$(function() {

  // Define our vars
  var moduleID = 5,
    output = "abc";
  $(this).data().moduleID.push(moduleID);
  $(this).data().output.push(output); 
    // ... Some more stuff ...

});

$(function() {
    // Define our vars
  var moduleID = 6,
    output = "def";
  $(this).data().moduleID.push(moduleID);
  $(this).data().output.push(output); 
  //Listen for button click
  $("[name=adminSearchGo]").click(function() {
    alert($(document).data().moduleID[0]); // No Access
  });
  console.log($(document).data())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="adminSearchGo" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

$(function(){ var a,b,c; }) all the vars( like a,b,c) defined inside of function are not available outside .you can consider it as an enclosures. 
1.define the var as a global one;
2.exports the var like "window.xxx = var(like a,b,c)"
3.exports a function that can access the var